# Recording with Correct FPS in Android (120FPS CamcorderProfile Not Working)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm using the following code to request that my phone (LG G5) record using the High Speed High Quality profile, which specifies 120FPS and 720p.

```
    CamcorderProfile mProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_HIGH);

    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    if (mNextVideoAbsolutePath == null || mNextVideoAbsolutePath.isEmpty()) {
        mNextVideoAbsolutePath = getVideoFilePath(getActivity());
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mNextVideoAbsolutePath);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(mProfile.videoBitRate);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(mProfile.videoFrameRate);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mProfile.videoFrameWidth, mProfile.videoFrameHeight);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

Unfortunately the frames per second specified are completely ignored.
My video is coming out at around 25FPS!
What can I do to fix this?

Thank you!!

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Never did!  We gave up and ended up going with a different device, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

On platform, media_profiles.xml defined the capability of video/audio encoder.
Take QC msm8998 for example:

```
   <EncoderProfile quality="high" fileFormat="mp4" duration="30">
  <Video codec="h264"
         bitRate="42000000"
         width="3840"
         height="2160"
         frameRate="30" />

  <Audio codec="aac"
         bitRate="156000"
         sampleRate="48000"
         channels="2" />
</EncoderProfile>
```

I think it may cause your video around 25FPS.

According to http://www.theandroidsoul.com/lg-g4-hacks-improve-camera-performance-60-fps-recording/, It seems increase fps by modify phone's config file is possible.